# How to promisify all callback-style methods in an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

I am relatively new to typescript. I would like to create a generic wrapper/utility that would take an object with callback-style methods (unknown in advance) and promisify them. The specific use case is to promisify auto-generated node grpc clients.

Example type for a client using callback-style methods:

```js
type AutogeneratedClient = {
    autogeneratedMethod(request: MethodSpecificRequestType, callback: (error: ServiceError, response: MethodSpecificResponseType) => void): ClientUnaryCall
}
```

I want to be able to have a generic "promisify" utility that would return an object as described by the following type:

```js
type PromisifiedAutogeneratedClient = {
    autogeneratedMethod(request: MethodSpecificRequestType): Promise<MethodSpecificResponseType>
}
```

I was thinking of implementing this as a Proxy that uses the "get" trap to return a wrapper function that promisifies the original callback-based method. Problem is, I don't know how to do it with Typescript. I started looking into Mapped types, but I am still unable to make this work.

How would you solve this problem in a type-safe way?

Comment: Many thanks to @Nikos for the exhaustive answer! The piece I was missing was the two helpers that extract the request and response parameter types, using conditional types and type inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking something along the lines of the following:

First, let's define some types. I do not know how gRPC generically defines its clients, so I will assume something like the one you have shown above:

```js
type GrpcClientFn<REQ, RES> =
  (req: REQ, cb: (e: ServiceError, res: RES)  => void) => ClientUnaryCall;
```

Which naturally leads us to the corresponding promisifeid type:

```js
type PromisifiedGrpcClientFn<REQ, RES> = (req: REQ) => Promise<RES>;
```

Now the type for *a single client function "promisifier"*, not exactly what you want, but a stepping stone to it, and an implementation:

```js
type Promisify<REQ, RES, F extends Function> =
  F extends GrpcClientFn<REQ, RES> ? PromisifiedGrpcClientFn<REQ, RES> : never;

function promisify<REQ, RES, FIN extends GrpcClientFn<REQ,RES>>(fin: FIN): PromisifiedGrpcClientFn<REQ, RES> {
  return function(req: REQ) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fin(req, (error, outcome) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(outcome);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

This takes a gRPC-style function and promisifies it. (Stylistically, I choose to use the old-style `function(a,b,c) { ... }` syntax over the modern `(a,b,c) => { ... }` syntax in some places, to make the return type explicit.)

Ok, the hard stuff gone: now define an entire object whose values are gRPC client functions:

```js
type GrpcClientObj = {
  [key: string]: GrpcClientFn<any, any>;
}
```

I wish I could do something better about the `<any,any>`, but I can't think of something!

Before defining the "promisified" object type, I need two helpers, to extract the request and response parameter types:

```js
// obtain type of request parameter
type PREQ<F extends Function> =
  F extends (req: infer REQ, cb: (e: ServiceError, res: any)  => void) => ClientUnaryCall ? REQ : never;
// obtain type of response parameter
type PRES<F extends Function> =
  F extends (req: any, cb: (e: ServiceError, res: infer RES)  => void) => ClientUnaryCall ? RES : never;
```

At last, the type of the "promisified" *object* is:

```js
type PromisifiedGrpcClientObj<T extends GrpcClientObj> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Promisify<PREQ<T[P]>, PRES<T[P]>, T[P]>;
}
```

And the implementation couldn't come easier:

```js
function promisifyObj(o: GrpcClientObj): PromisifiedGrpcClientObj<GrpcClientObj> {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((aggr, cur) => ({
    ...aggr,
    [cur]: promisify(o[cur])
  }), {} as PromisifiedGrpcClientObj<GrpcClientObj>);
}
```

And a [Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITACwPYBMDKADhAsDMAgEoQCOArhAM5gAqAnscgN4CwAUPwC+-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-ruHqDNfd6taoBg0FzOYQRLVJLJ8nWVOQW1acBAbAZbOZb0Z7MzXL+EQTPaRyALRZLAuBQrRlZbIfddZ9fpAAaPrrbDQ1RSnwz7xKWsmHlKg1MYHZAXbUaJnTIvPObJysuPKRImaKbsghbFlAxq7pw6ZygA8uMABWTaOAUADaUwQGwrTMFAoApAAuq0yGRlmcKTmwwx0fcxpaGWyaSuQ0rhqhGFwiwV6hlRmZoehqrYcgOFCsgoDIPhbDYDAyAsBRSZiimMBWvuyK8RJZH3MMmn4NpQq6cMLA6UxALaDAXpntYRQlGkhblFkBx1LeTRgPsRh4EcZjdI0fSXI+YyTAgMwDu+L4rG+GxjpY5wkq5HR+RYZy7Jc2pPEB7yLpyQTcmM+RxWAdBQCA3CCEU7qgflK5eMxGjWfW57IJAzAAIy1DA7WzIsbSHKYXQWL0zAZQubEQHCSW+UNpw7BcAz3DcXDOHwTW2eVhCqexVoxj2+B2gAkgAcvx7qCV8Coxnm9xdaArTQidOVsamF1RtasaPGJDQlWVyDrQ2IDtuuy1YoUP2leVhYAO4qXqEoQLUOKMNgXjFtS6EkGAmViYU-2gOqwxzO+wzYEkCB6tcC643jUkKcTCyg3wtO0w0mM+gzqhXMaLMFJVEBeLYRW83FKNo4jZNgBTorXDzvNaCzgjc2DfPK8zyBaKtAMtVt8M7cJtTYJRXHUcJz3ba9JtCTxb1gMJX1gxDf3CVjAB0smMIbVyuw0uB0EgSNwCkKQfiMpWZbUNOu9HQch4MKviQgpXKbrFrqYbOFJ1AZFXGDSvDCtVVw2nvhplbXzCXCtv22rWhAA).

EDIT: Maybe, the following would be more appropriate - the difference is how we define the output type in relation to the input type:

```js
function promisifyObj<GRPCO extends GrpcClientObj>(o: GRPCO): PromisifiedGrpcClientObj<GRPCO> {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((aggr, cur) => ({
    ...aggr,
    [cur]: promisify(o[cur])
  }), {} as PromisifiedGrpcClientObj<GRPCO>);
}
```